# failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:7199: connection refused

Tags: solr, cassandra, rhel, datastax, datastax-enterprise

I am getting error `failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:7199: connection refused` when I do a `nodetool status` on my RHEL machine. It was working fine until yesterday but today it suddenly started giving this error. I did not make any changes to the configuration files.

I have DSE installed and properly configured as it was running fine till yesterday from past 3-4 months. The cassandra.yaml has the cluster name, seed, rpc address, rpc port, listen address all configured correctly. Also I set `-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=<server ip address>;` in cassandra-env.sh. Still did not work. Nor am I able to connect to cqlsh, nor my SOLR is accessible after this. Also I have allowed all ports on my security group on my machine to check if it is any port problem but it is not.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Not really a programming question but does `netstat` show anything listening on port 7199?

Comment: yes, it shows state as established

Comment: Okay, when you `telnet 127.0.0.1 7199`, do you get the connection refused?

Comment: Hang on, did you say 'established'? Is there an entry that says 'listening'? You'll need `netstat -na`.

Comment: no there is no entry saying listening, just one saying established.

Comment: I'm think that's a problem right there. Unfortunately I don't know enough about RH to guide further but I'd be suggesting that no listener means no-one can connect.

Comment: So you mean to say, the problem is with my port right? it is not getting allowed right?

Comment: This doesn't look like a port blockage (such as firewall) since, even then, you'd be able to see a server listening on the local box. This looks like the server itself is not running.

Comment: Is DSE running in your environment `ps -ef|grep dse`?

Comment: yeah, I agree that cassandra isn't running. check the system.log for errors - particularly out-of-memory errors.

Comment: I checked and found out that dse is not running on my environment. Will check the log for the error. Thanks

Comment: have you found any solution to start cassandra if not running

Comment: what does your system log say.. most installs its in/var/log/cassandra/system.log  That should have a definitive error message

Answer (score 1):

Check your `/etc/cassandra/cassandra.yaml` file. It should be like

```
authenticator: AllowAllAuthenticator
```

Problem may be caused of this.

Comment: Solved this for me! But is this okay from a security perspective?

Comment: Solving this brings me the next problem: `Cassandra 3.0 and later require Java 8u40 or later.` My version IS later, grrr Cassandra.

Comment: Wait, I can't reproduce this actually solving it for me, plus the line already is in `/etc/cassandra/cassandra.yaml` anyway. Wish I could take back my upvote.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error, and it worked for me after the following commands:

```
systemctl start cassandra    
systemctl restart cassandra
```